# Getting syntax error insert Class body to complete class declaration for the class "convert to binary"

Tags: java

```
 class decimaltobinary{
    int y= 56;
    int array[] = new int[10];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        converttobinary con = new converttobinary();

    }

    class converttobinary{  //Error occurring at this line 

        for(int i = 0; i<11;i++) {
            while(y > 0) {

                int x = y%2;
                array[i]= x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// Error occurring at the class convert to binary. 
// It says insert Class body to complete class declaration.

Comment: Your `for` loop must belong to some method.

Answer (score 1):

Well the error speaks for itself.

> Insert Class body to complete class declaration.

For loops must be either inside a method or a block.

```
class converttobinary {
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            while (y > 0) {
                int x = y % 2;
                array[i] = x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

And then you'll have another problem in your code.

> Non-static variables cannot be referenced from a static context.

When you are coding in the main method note that it is static (`public static void main(...)`) so either you have to make all variables static or create a new instance of `decimaltobinary` class.

Easiest way to solve this is by creating a new instance of `decimaltobinary`

```
converttobinary con = new decimaltobinary().new converttobinary();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code must be kept inside some method :

```
for(int i = 0; i<11;i++) {
            while(y > 0) {

                int x = y%2;
                array[i]= x;
            }
        }
```